# How can create fix btn with angular-snap.js in snap-content ellement

Tags: css, angularjs, scroll

how can create position fixed in snap-content element 
for example make

```css
... { position: fixed; top: 5rem; right: 0; }
```

```html
<button class="..." snap-toggle="right">Toggle Right</button>
```

[in this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iB8VfD?p=preview)

and when scrolling the page position of the button did not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for temporary solution adding this code with jquery

```
$('#ScrollElemntID').scroll(function () {
    var $win = $('#ScrollElemntID');
    $('.btnFix').css('top', $win.scrollTop());
});
```